# Prove that $A\geq I$ implies that $A$ is invertible.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces, c-star-algebras

Here's the question:

> Let $A$ be a positive operator on a (possibly infinite dimensional) Hilbert space.  Let $I$ denote the identity operator.  Suppose that $A \geq I$, which is to say that $A - I$ is a positive operator.  Prove that $A$ is invertible.

I think that this is true, but I haven't been able to find a proof one way or the other.  I would like to avoid invoking any heavy machinery (like the spectral theorem) if possible.  I would also be interested in a proof that carries over to more general $C^*$ algebras.

Of course, the proof in the case of finite dimensional spaces is fairly obvious, since it suffices to show that the operator has a trivial kernel.  Since that does *not* suffice here, I really have no clue what my next move should be.

Any guidance here would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand your question, but here is what I have: $$\|Ax\|\|x\|\ge(Ax,x)\ge (Ix,x)=\|x\|^2\Rightarrow \|Ax\|\ge 1\cdot \|x\|$$
So if $Ax=Ay$ then $0\ge \|x-y\|$.

Comment: @Svetoslav right.  So, certainly $A$ is injective.  However, in infinite dimensional spaces, this is not enough.

Comment: But if it is linear , then it is enough, right ?

Comment: No. For example, take the [right shift operator](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shift_operator#Sequences), or an integration operator.

Comment: I do not get it.  If the operator is linear, then it has to be invertible. Even with a bounded Inverse.

Comment: @Svetoslav the right-shift operator has no *two-sided* inverse.

Comment: Sorry, but I still think that injectivity is enough for $A$ to have two sided inverse defined on $R(A)$. Another thing is to show that actually $R(A)=H$

Comment: Yes, if you want an inverse that's defined on $R(A)$, then that's enough (no, this inverse will not necessarily be bounded). However, what *I* mean (and what mathematicians generally mean) when they refer to *the inverse* of a function $f:A \to B$ is a function $g:B \to A$ satisfying $g \circ f = id_A$ and $f \circ g = id_B$.

Comment: If $v\in R(A)\Rightarrow \exists u\in H: Au=v\Rightarrow \|v\|=\|Au\|\ge \|u\|=\|A^{-1}v\|$ Therefore $\|A^{-1}\|\leq 1$

Comment: @Svetoslav if that's the case, then what about the operator
$$
T[(x_1,x_2,x_3,\dots)] = (x_1/1,x_2/2,x_3/3,\dots)
$$
does *this* operator have a bounded inverse?

Comment: @Svetoslav oh, I see.  We can easily deduce that the operator $A$ from my question has a bounded inverse defined on its range, if we think of it as the operator $A:X \to \mathfrak{R}(A)$.  Interesting point.

Comment: I am glad we have a consensus :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It shouldn't be to hard to show that $A$ is injective, for if $Ax = 0$ then $$\langle x,x \rangle \le \langle Ax,x\rangle =0.$$

It will follow that $A$ is invertible once we show that $A$ is surjective: the range $R(A)$ satisfies $R(A) = H$.

Let $A^*$ denote the adjoint of $A$.  Suppose that $y \in N(A^*)$ so that $A^*y = 0$.  Then $$0 = \langle y,A^*y \rangle = \langle Ay,y \rangle \ge \langle y,y \rangle$$ so that $N(A^*) = \{0\}$. Consequently $R(A)^\perp = \{0\}$.

You can use the projection theorem to conclude that $R(A) = H$ provided that $R(A)$ is closed.  Suppose that $\{y_k\}$ is a sequence in $R(A)$ that converges to a point $y \in H$ and let $x_k \in H$ satisfy $A x_k = y_k$.  Then
$$ \langle x_k - x_j, x_k - x_j \rangle \le \langle Ax_k - Ax_j, x_k - x_j \rangle \le \|Ax_k - Ax_j\| \|x_k - x_j\|.$$  Since $\{A x_k\}$ is Cauchy in $H$, it follows that $\{x_k\}$ is Cauchy too, hence $x_k \to x$ for some $x$, which by continuity will satisfy $Ax = y$. Thus $R(A)$ is closed.

Comment: To clarify for future readers: we then have then met the hypothesis of the [bounded inverse theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_inverse_theorem).

Comment: You're welcome. The formula $R(A)^\perp = N(A^*)$ comes in handy frequently.

Comment: @UmbertoP. Do we assume that $A$ is linear ?

Comment: I do not know how adjoint is defined for nonlinear operator.

Comment: @Svetoslav: "operator" here means linear operator.

Comment: @hardmath so this is the so called condition that $A$ is bounded away from $0$. For such operators it is true that they are invertible (at least left sided) and the inverse is bounded.

Comment: Another useful fact is: $||Ax|| \geq c ||x||$ for all $x \in V$ for some $c> 0$ if and only if $A$ is injective and has closed range. ($V$ Banach)

Answer (score 2):

Since $A$ is positive, its spectrum is contained in $[0,\infty)$. Then the spectrum of $A+I$ is contained in $[1,\infty)$; thus $0$ is not in the spectrum of $A+I$ and $A+I$ is invertible.

To justify that the spectrum translates note that $A+I-\lambda I=A-(\lambda-1)I$. So $A+I-\lambda$ is not invertible precisely when $A-(\lambda -1)I$ is not invertible, i.e. when $\lambda-1$ is in the spectrum of $A$. So 
$$
\sigma(A+I)=\{\lambda+I:\ \lambda\in\sigma(A)\} 
$$

Comment: Care to explain the downvote, please?

Comment: Nice answer. Any quick justification that the spectrum is in $[0,\infty)?$

Comment: That depends on your definition of positivity. You asked about an operator in $B(H)$, but also asked about arbitrary C$^*$-algebras. What does "$A$ positive" mean?

Comment: $A = T^*T$ for some $T$ would be nice, but $\langle x,Ax \rangle \geq 0$ for all $x$ will do.

Comment: The canonical way is to define "positive" as "selfadjoint with non-negative spectrum". If you want to start from $A=T^*T$, I think it is a bit of a struggle to understand the spectrum. If you start with $\langle Ax,x\rangle\geq0$, then probably the easy way is to argue as in Umberto's answer to show that $A-\lambda I$ is invertible whenever $\lambda<0$.