# If $T$ is a positive operator then $I+T$ is invertible

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $T$ be a positive operator on a Hilbert space $H$, prove that $I+T:H\to H$ is invertible and $(I+T)^{-1} \in B(H)$.

Now, If I prove $I+T$ is invertible, the bounded inverse theorem implies the second part. Now while proving that $I+T$ is invertible, I have proved that $I+T$ is one-one. But now I have to prove that $I+T$ is onto. In doing so my idea is to prove that $I+T$ is bounded below, so that $Range(I+T)$ becomes closed and then show that $Range(I+T)^{\perp}=\{\ 0 \}\ $, then by projection theorem we will have $Range(I+T)=H$.

But I couldn't execute this idea. Other ideas will also be appreciated

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Are you saying that $T$ is not necessarily a bounded operator?

Comment: No, I am assuming that $T$ is bounded. The definiton of positive operator that I am using is $T$ is bounded self adjoint operator on a Hilbert space such that $\langle Tx,x \rangle \geq 0$.

Comment: Okay, thanks for clarifying.

Comment: I'd call that a non-negative operator, though.

Comment: Some answers are given [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1456658/81360); perhaps one will suit your needs

Comment: @Roland both are standard in functional analysis

Comment: @Omnomnomnom I have shown that $Range(T+I)^{\perp}= \{\ 0 \}\ $. I just need to show that $Range(T+I)$ is closed, which i am having trouble. The link you gave is very similar but not exactly same. can you help me to show the range is closed?

Comment: Take $A = T + I$, and apply this from an answer on the other question: *Suppose that $\{y_k\}$ is a sequence in $R(A)$ that converges to a point $y \in H$ and let $x_k \in H$ satisfy $A x_k = y_k$.  Then
$$ \langle x_k - x_j, x_k - x_j \rangle \le \langle Ax_k - Ax_j, x_k - x_j \rangle \le \|Ax_k - Ax_j\| \|x_k - x_j\|.$$  Since $\{A x_k\}$ is Cauchy in $H$, it follows that $\{x_k\}$ is Cauchy too, hence $x_k \to x$ for some $x$, which by continuity will satisfy $Ax = y$. Thus $R(A)$ is closed.*

Comment: @Omnomnomnom Got it Thanks!!

Comment: I believe this holds for general unital C$^\ast$-algebras: If $a$ is positive in a C$^\ast$-algebra $A$, then $1_A \leq a + 1_A$ and any positive element in a unital C$^\ast$-algebra dominating the unit is invertible (the spectrum is contained in $[1,\infty)$.

Comment: @Omnomnomnom In fact $\langle Tx,x\rangle\geq 0$ implies $T$ is self-adjoint and bounded.

Comment: @C.Ding I suppose assuming that $\langle Tx,x \rangle$ is defined for all $x$ is a lot. If $T$ were merely "densely defined", we might run into trouble though.

Answer (score 8):

Note that 
$$
I+T-\lambda I=T-(\lambda -1)I.
$$
So $\lambda\in\sigma(I+T)\iff \lambda-1\in\sigma(T)$. In other words, 
$$
\sigma(I+T)=\{\lambda+1:\ \lambda\in\sigma(T)\}.
$$
As $T$ is positive, $\sigma(T)\subset[0,\infty)$. Thus $\sigma(I+T)\subset [1,\infty)$.

It follows that $0\not\in\sigma(I+T)$, so $I+T$ is invertible.

Answer (score 3):

Let $A=I+T$. Recall $\ker A^* = (\operatorname{ran} A)^\perp$. For injective self-adjoint operators, this already implies that the range is dense. But your operator is not just injective but is *bounded from below*, meaning  there is $c>0$ such that 
$$\|Ax\|\ge c\|x\| \quad \forall x \tag{1}$$
Property (1) implies $\operatorname{ran} A$ is closed.  To summarize: a self-adjoint operator that is bounded from below is invertible.

The proof of (1) is an application of monotonicity:
$$
\langle x+Tx, x+Tx\rangle  \ge \langle x, x\rangle
$$ 
so $c=1$ works.

Answer (score 1):

A linear operator $T$ on a $\mathbb R$-Hilbert space is nonnegative if and only if $-T$ is dissipative. This immediately implies that $\lambda+T$ is injective for all $\lambda>0$; see, for example, Proposition 3.14-i in *One-Parameter Semigroups for Linear Evolution Equations* by Engel and Nagel.

In particular, $\lambda+T$ is bounded from below (in the operator sense) with constant $\lambda$ and $(\lambda+T)^{-1}$ has operator norm at most $\lambda^{-1}$.